# Putting data from 3 text files into 3 variables

Tags: php

I have the following code, which gets the data from 3 text files and puts them into 3 variables. How can I refactor this to make it smaller?

```
$handle = fopen($template_filename, "r");
if (filesize($template_filename) > 0)
{
    $email_template = fread($handle, filesize($template_filename));
}
fclose($handle);

// get the subject from a text file
$handle = fopen($subject_filename, "r");
if (filesize($subject_filename) > 0)
{
    $subject_template = fread($handle, filesize($subject_filename));
}
fclose($handle);

// get the footer from a text file
$handle = fopen($footer_filename, "r");
if (filesize($footer_filename) > 0)
{
    $footer_template = fread($handle, filesize($footer_filename));
}
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, you can use [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$email_template = file_get_contents($template_filename);
$subject_template = file_get_contents($subject_filename);
$footer_template = file_get_contents($footer_filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the repetitive parts in a function `openFile()`, open files with `file_get_contents`, and finally, check for empty file size via strlen in the ternary and return the contents or an error ("Empty file." in this case - would suggest you replace with an error function call or something).

```
function openFile($filename){
    $contents  = file_get_contents($filename);
    return strlen($contents) > 0 ? $contents : "Empty file.";
}

$email_template = openFile($email_filename);
$subject_template = openFile($subject_filename);
$footer_template = openFile($footer_filename);

# Test case
echo openFile("http://www.google.com");
```